# Como se definir Foreign key no oracle SQL developer?

Tags: oracle, sqldeveloper

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou nova usando este programa, como se define Foreign key no oracle SQL developer?

Comment: Clica com o botão direito no nome da tabela e escolhe as opções "constraint > Add foreign key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clique com o direito na tabela em que deseja adicionar a FK, selecione o menu `Constraint` e então selecione `Add Foreign Key`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Na janela que abrir, preencha as informações:

- *Name*: nome da sua FK
- *Column Name*: é a coluna da sua tabela de chave estrangeira
- *Reference Table Name*: é a tabela de chave primária
- *Referencing Column*: é a chave primaria da sua tabela de referência

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique no botão *Apply*

---

Referência:

- [DOCS.ORACLE, Database 2 Day Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_creating.htm)